# CrystalReportsRedist2005_x86.msm for VS 2005

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

I have an old Visual Studio 2005 web project which I need to re-host. I remember from years back, in order for the Crystal Reports to run, you had to build the project with a merge module which is CrystalReportsRedist2005_x86.msm.

I no longer have this file, and I can't find it for download anywhere. It used to be on the Business objects website, but I can't find it now.

Does anyone know where I can get a copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try https://code.google.com/p/cims2/downloads/detail?name=CRRedist2005_x86.msi&can=2&q=

or  search for CRRedist2005_x86.msi

Comment: What a handy site. Can't believe I've never thought of searching that site before - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this website or just do a general google search for Crystal Reports Redistributable x86

http://tcsoftware.net/blog/2011/05/crystal-reports-redistributable-download-net-2005/